# Install the package from the GitHub on Colab

Tags: python

I install it on the Colab

```
pip install xicor
```

But it shows an error

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
flask 1.1.4 requires click<8.0,>=5.1, but you have click 8.1.3 which is incompatible.
datascience 0.10.6 requires coverage==3.7.1, but you have coverage 6.4.1 which is incompatible.
datascience 0.10.6 requires folium==0.2.1, but you have folium 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
coveralls 0.5 requires coverage<3.999,>=3.6, but you have coverage 6.4.1 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed black-22.6.0 click-8.1.3 coverage-6.4.1 mypy-extensions-0.4.3 pathspec-0.9.0 platformdirs-2.5.2 pytest-cov-2.9.0 typed-ast-1.5.4 xicor-1.0.1
```

Comment: Sounds more like a warning to me :)

Comment: You might run into some issues with the version of coverage, which you could downgrade to 3.7.1 tho. Might be worth making a venv just for the purpose

Answer (score 0):

It is just a warning... Click on `Runtime > Restart runtime` after installation, it should be fixed.